# Changed Files Only Development Subfolder: Selective .htaccess Redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say I have a site at `http://example.com`.  The Example App is a php web app with hundreds of files located at `/`, `/shop/`, `/shop/items/`, etc;.  I want to develop by saving files to `http://example.com/dev/`.  However, I don't want to have an entire copy of a few gigabytes (for arguments sake) of files - I'm working on a few files at a time, and only need those to be in the `dev` folder.

Assume the following files exist:

1. `http://example.com/dev/index.php`
2. `http://example.com/dev/shop/flax.php`
3. `http://example.com/dev/shop/items/623.php`

If I navigate to any of those urls, I'd like the appropriate files to be loaded.  However, `http://example.com/dev/index.php` links to `contact.php`, `login.php`, and `about.php`.  Those files are unchanged and therefore I did not make a development copy.

Is there a good way to A) **internally** redirect any missing files or folders in /dev/ to their matching files without `/dev/` from the production site, but **without changing the url,** (within one site that is possible right?) and B) **maintaining redirects to dev copies** that exist if the user started at the `/dev/` site?

This is how far I got (.htaccess in the `/dev` folder), it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /dev/(.+)$ http://example.com/$1
```

TL;DR:  How can you have a fully functioning/virtually isolated development copy of a php site in a subfolder of that site which actually only contains versions of any files that you want to override the parent folder's copy?